# ASP Core - Controller force params

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I'm building a library which need to be the more generic possible . So I have a controller really simple

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    object _repo;
    public AdminController(object repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    ...
}
```

Now I'd like to tell ASP in my webapp to use this controller with the `Repository` class without the need that Repository inherit from an interface.

Something like, ok if you need to instantiate a AdminController object, just pass the Repository the same way you do for the other controllers which need a Repository param.

I already try to do so in the Startup.cs file but it does nothing

```
services.AddScoped<AdminController>(c => {
    Console.WriteLine("We need you");
    return new AdminController(c.GetService<IRepository>());
});
```

Comment: I am pretty confused by your question.  You seem to be getting something that implements `IRepository` already, so your line about "with the Repository class without the need that Repository inherit from an interface", it looks like you will only get things that implement an interface.  Also, why would your controller not just take an `IRepository`?  This really seems like an XY problem

Comment: I am building a library and I don't want that the repo passed as parameter of the constructor need to inherit from anything, don't think about the context if you do not understand my objective, just how wan i achieve it. The fact is that the implementation oft the repository is not in the same project that the library and i want to use my library everywhere without constraint. Maybe the exemple is not good but it's simple enough to understand what i want to achieve i think

Answer (score 0):

Maybe generics could help you?

```
public class AdminController<T> : Controller
{
    private readonly T _repo;

    public AdminController(T repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    ...
}

services.AddScoped<AdminController<IRepository>>(c => {
    Console.WriteLine("We need you");
    return new AdminController<IRepository>(c.GetService<IRepository>());
});
```